# Configure DNS routing in wireguard

Tags: vpn, internal-dns

Can anyone help to configure routing in wireguard, please?

**What i have:** Linux server with installed wireguard, unbound dns, pihole, seafile. router keenetic speedster iptables is set to deny 80 port to all, and allow only for wireguard local users. for services, I made local domain names in pi-hole that point to 10.0.0.1 - the address of the server on the wireguard network

**What i can do now:** I can connect to wireguard network with wg interface, and if all traffic goes through wireguard, i can access fake domain names like fakedomain.com to access seafile or other resources.

**What i need:** I want to split the traffic so that I can access resources in the local wireguard network via vpn, and all others via the provider's network.

**My configurations:**

**WG-server**

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.1/24
ListenPort = 56777
PrivateKey = privateKey
MTU = 1450
PostUp = iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -o ens3 -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE; iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; sysctl -q -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE; iptables -t mangle -D POSTROUTING -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -o ens3 -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu; sysctl -q -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=0

[Peer]
PublicKey = publikKey
PresharedKey = presharedKey
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.6/32
```

**WG-client:**

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.6/32
PrivateKey = privateKey
DNS = 10.0.0.1
[Peer]
PublicKey = publicKey
PresharedKey = presharedKey
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = 188.119.112.63:56777
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

**Iptables:**

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N f2b-sshd
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j f2b-sshd
-A INPUT -s 10.0.0.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 10.0.0.0/24 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 10.0.0.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 10.0.0.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5000 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 10.0.0.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5000 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j DROP
-A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
```

for the test, I created a route to dnsleaktest.com 23.239.16.110 specified the wireguard subnet and as a result, during the test, the ip of my server is displayed everything is fine, when i go to another site to check the ip, the dynamic address given by the provider is displayed 178.140.42.115

When I write a route to my own server, through the internal ip - 10.0.0.1 - I can connect to it at this address, I can access resources, but only by the local ip and port. By the names that I gave on the pi-hole local DNS - I can not enter.
So i need to configure dns routing, but i don't know how to make it correct.

I tried to change the wireguard config and specify the following settings:

```
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ens3 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.1:53
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ens3 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.1:53
PostDown = iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i ens3 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.1:53
PostDown = iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i ens3 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.1:53
```

In this case, everything starts to work as it should, but, for some reason, after 2-3 minutes I again get an error that DNS cannot be resolved, after I turn it off and on again, on the wireguard router, everything works again for 2 - 3 minutes and then turns off.

**Config of router:**

[Main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Rolv.png)

[Routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cffdW.png)

Answer (score 3):

In the Wireguard Client setting, you can specify a domain through which DNS server to go using PostUP:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.1/24
PrivateKey = somePrivateKey
PostUp = resolvectl dns %i 10.0.0.1 10.0.0.2; resolvectl domain %i ~fakedomain.com

[Peer]
PublicKey = somePubliceKey
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = 1.2.3.4:60000
```

Answer (score 2):

I have added a remote DNS server in my configuration from Wireguard via adding
"DNS = [DNS Server IP]" in the Wireguard Interface section.

i.e.:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx=
Address = 192.168.10.20/32
DNS = 192.168.10.130
```

Comment: That require the `resolvconf` command which is not installed at least on ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, it was stupid, it was enough to register the same dns 10.0.0.1 on the main connection as on the wireguard interface

Comment: What do you mean by "main connection" ? `wg0.config` on wireguard server side?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also trying to get DNS and http/https running over wireguard for 2 days in a similar setup as you and still failing with name resolution.
What exactly do you mean by "register the same dns ... on the main connection as on the wireguard interface". Do you think it is enough to write the key-value pair "DNS = [WG Server IP]" in the interface section of the client and the server? I would be really happy about a hint.

Regards, Martin

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/500277)